# Java crash SIGSEGV (0xb) on Java 8

Tags: debian, java-8, segmentation-fault

Running a minecraft server on a Debian 7 64 Bit machine.
Oracle Java 8_05 JRE 64 bit is installed.
Since some time the server crashes twice or more times a day.

Java crash report:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0921139a9c, pid=25246, tid=139676902000384
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x555a9c]  G1ParCopyClosure<false, (G1Barrier)2, false>::copy_to_survivor_space(oopDesc*)+0x3c
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

How can I solve it?

Forgot to mention that I use these start parameters:

```
    SERVICE="spigot.jar"
    MEMLOG="memory.log"
    SCREEN="classic"
    CPU_COUNT=4
    INITMEM="2048M"
    MAXMEM="12G"
    INVOCATION="java -Xms$INITMEM -Xmx$MAXMEM -XX:+AggressiveOpts - XX:ParallelGCThreads=$CPU_COUNT -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -Xloggc:$MEMLOG -jar $SERVICE nogui -o false"
```

screen -dmS $SCREEN $INVOCATION

Anything that could cause the trouble? Maybe the GC flag?

Comment: Do you specifically need JRE 1.8? Can't you run Minecraft using Debian default JVM?

Comment: This is likely a bug. Enable core dumps, get to reproduce the error and file a bug on JVM bugzilla.

Comment: Used Oracle JRE for 3 years now. Our server version had troubles with JVM in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is occurring in

`V  [libjvm.so+0x555a9c]  G1ParCopyClosure<false, (G1Barrier)2, false>::copy_to_survivor_space(oopDesc*)+0x3c`,

which appears to be part of the garbage collector (assuming that the naming is similar to the one in [OpenJDK](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~johnc/6865703/webrev.00/raw_files/new/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/g1CollectedHeap.cpp)). That is not something you have direct control over, so this is likely a bug in the Java implementation. The best you can do is to report it to Oracle.

Comment: Could one of my GC flags causing this?

Comment: Generally, a GC flag should not cause a SIGSEGV, especially not the ones that you've listed. Is it possible to use another GC than G1GC (I am not familiar with Oracle's JVM, but your argument list hints at this as a possibility)? If yes, it would be worth a try, since the method in which the fault occurs seems to belong to G1.

Comment: Not using the G1 GC "fixed" the problem